# Save Live Video Stream To Local Storage

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, rtsp

**Problem:**

```
I have to save live video streams data which come as an RTP packets from RTSP Server.
The data come in two formats : MPEG4 and h264. 
I do not want to encode/decode input stream.
Just write to a file which is playable with proper codecs.
```

Any advice?

Best Wishes

**History:**

**My Solutions and their problems:**

**Firt attempt:** FFmpeg

```
I use FFmpeg libary to get audio and video rtp packets. 
But in order to write packets i have to use av_write_frame : 
which seems that decode /encode takes place.
Also, when i give output format as mp4 ( av_guess_format("mp4", NULL, NULL)
the output file is unplayable. 
[ any way ffmpeg has bad doc. hard to find what is wrong]
```

**Second attempth**: DirectShow

```
Then i decide to use DirectShow. I found a RTSP Source Filter. 
Then a Mux and File Writer.
Cretae Single graph:

RTSP Source --> MPEG MUX ---> File Writer

It worked but the problem is that  the output file is not playable
if graph is not stoped. If something happens, graph crashed for example
the output file is not playable
Also i can able to write H264 data, but the video is completely unplayable.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MP4 file format has an index that is required for correct playback, and the index can only be created once you've finished recording. So any solution using MP4 container files (and other indexed files) is going to suffer from the same problem. You need to stop the recording to finalise the file, or it will not be playable.

One solution that might help is to break the graph up into two parts, so that you can keep recording to a new file while stopping the current one. There's an example of this at www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge.

If you try the GDCL MP4 multiplexor, and you are having problems with H264 streams, see the related question [GDCL Mpeg-4 Multiplexor Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174149/gdcl-mpeg-4-multiplexor-problem)

Comment: Thanks Davies. I will check GDCL Mpeg-4 Multiplexor Problem.